# How to change help language in SVN on Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, locale

How to change the language of commands' documentation under **Windows**, printed by following command:
    svn help checkout

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `LANG` environment variable

```
set LANG=en_US
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using IntelliJ and couldn't set an environment variable. So I deleted the `de` folder from `Program Files\SlikSvn\Share\Locale` and the client fell back to using English.

Comment: "dirty" but perfect for me, only affecting svn output... :-)